# Ruby / Rails naming conventions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, naming-conventions

If I generate a scaffold called `"product"`, what are the differences between the following when I use them in coding my app? `@products`, `@product`, `@Product`, `@Products`, `Products`, `Product`, `product`, and `products` (I'm pretty sure those aren't all used, but it should at least give the idea of what I'm referring to).

I can't seem to find a simple explanation of what each combination of `@`/capitalization/plurality means. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reserved word is capitalized `Product` and this references the object model. For example to get all products and save it in the variable `@products` you would do:

```
@products = Product.all
@product = Product.find(1)
```

If you left off the `@` sign off of 'products' then it would be saved only as a local variable and your view would not be able to access it.

In this example `@products` and `@product` are variables you declare in the controller. You could just use:

```
@lotsofproducts = Product.all
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! Seems I forgot that I added the @products variable to controller while blindly following examples in the book. Other answers were very helpful as well, but I'm a sucker for example code.

Answer (score 9):

You can read
[Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) and [Rails style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide), and you get answer on your question.

Comment: +1 for surprised and its useful, I wonder how you can find these info. Is your github account?

Answer (score 4):

For Ruby naming conventions, you can check here:
http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_names.html

As for Rails' naming conventions, it's linguistic: Model - singular, Controller - plural, DatabaseTable - plural(snake_case), View(directory name) - plural.
You can check from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: Just wrote some stuff from the first link on my whiteboard for reference. Thx.